# Find a substring which does not contain particuler but contain any other specific word --RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am facing a problem in C# to find a substring that does not contain a particular word but contain specific word.

Ex :

**Input string  :**  Computer is a fantastic **dev**ise  .Will **dev**id come?.

**restrict** : find "dev" where string does n't conta "id"  . and replace with "Rox-"

**Output string** :  Computer is a fantastic **Roxise**  .Will devid come?.

It's just a example ,so my filter string can be anything and it will come dynamically.

I need to done this in RegEx C#

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What is the expected output for the following test case: `Devit Devkjasid iddevg devaijd devitkjdevks`?

Answer (score 0):

```
yourstr=Regex.Replace(yourstr,"(?i)dev(?!\S*id)","Rox");
```

**Input** : Computer is a fantastic devise .Will devid comedevkkid?.

**Output**: Computer is a fantastic Roxise .Will devid comedevkkid?.

Is this what you want ?

Comment: Yes perfect. Can we replace sub-string which comes in middle of string only . If same sub string comes in  middle and left /right of string then it should be ignored. for example ,Input : "ashoooash ooooashooashoo oooooash" .                                 Output : "ashoooash ooooSuccessooSucessoo oooooash"  ..  Replace "ash" with "Success" text.